# magento 2 store manager always returns default store id

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

I'm implementing module which have to store different data for all stores, so i need get current store id and set id to db with new records. I'm trying get store id this way

`$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();`

But when i change scope to another store (which has id "2") then $storeId still has value "1" (default store). I see that last param in my url has changed
`store/2/`
but in code has returned default store id. Any idea what causing that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your assumption that when changing the configuration scope you also change the the backend scope, which is not so. See the following issue in github for a solution to your problem:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9741.

tl;dr: get the store id from request params: `$this->_request->getParam('store', 0)`